# Where should I store a cookie?

Tags: c#, windows, cookies, .net-4.0

I have a WPF app that talks to a web server.  It needs to save a session cookie when it closes for subsequent use.  What is the right way to do this?  I could put it in a config file, isolated storage, or a plain text file but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: a jar....sorry sorry couldn't resist.

Comment: @harper89 OP says he's using .NET; your solution only works in Java.

Comment: @djacobson, whoosh...jar as in cookie jar.  I keep wanting to put cookie monster references in this code I'm working on :P.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing user settings now for your application?  I would probably choose the same area.

If no area is currently specified, probably an application settings file (user.config) is the best spot for it.

Comment: I have a settings file.  I thought about putting it there.  I was just wondering if there was a "standard" place for cookies.  There doesn't appear to be though.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` is easy to use. You simply define a setting of type `List<Cookie>` and then you use it like so:

```
public List<Cookie> Cookies {
    get {
        return Settings.Default.Cookies;
    }
    set {
        Settings.Default.Cookies = value;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd need to define the type `Cookie`.

To create the setting, go to your application properties (right click the project and select properties), then go to the Settings tab.